# navigateForward doesn't trigger constructor in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I send data between pages like this:

```
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['artist-info-page'], {
    state: {
      fullArtist: item,
      simpleSearch: true
    }
  })
```

Most of the times this triggers the constructor of 'artist-info-page', where I read the state like this:

```
this.artistInfoParams.fullArtist = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.fullArtist
```

But sometimes navigateForward doesn't trigger the constructor, so I can't retrieve the parameters. It simply calls ionViewWillEnter, where from my understanding I have no access to the router's navigation state.

I also tried moving to router.navigate instead of using NavController, I switched for one page and the behavior is the same. I haven't switched my entire project as I use NavController a lot and it doesn't seem to help.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug and if so, do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to solve this by defining my own service for data transfer between pages. I based my decision on this great [link](https://ionicacademy.com/pass-data-angular-router-ionic-4/). I implemented something simpler for now, as it was enough for me - a simple class with only one parameter called state:

```
export class DataServiceProvider {

    public state: any;

}
```

Then I simply fill the state parameter before navigating to the page:

```
var localState = {
  fullArtist: item,
  simpleSearch: true
};
this.dataService.state = localState;
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('artist-info-page');
```

And retrieve it in the page:

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    var localState = this.dataService.state;
  }
```

Of course, there's space for some improvement in the future, for example making sure the state is not preserved from an older page transition (when the current state needs no state).